# Llenar una matriz de 6x6 con 12 valores de forma aleatoria y repetir cada elemento 3 veces

Tags: c++, pseint

Puedo llenar la matriz de forma aleatoria, pero en la ejecución los elementos del arreglo se repiten más de 3 veces, en otros casos hay espacios de la matriz que se quedan vacíos o simplemente se repiten una o dos veces, las instrucciones son generar un vector de 12 números aleatorios sin repetirse, luego crear una matriz de 6x6 y llenarla de manera aleatoria con el vector y que cada valor del vector se repita 3 veces en la matriz, pero como se puede observar en la imagen de salida no se cumple

Adjunto el código de lo que he hecho

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
int a,b,c,d,f,h,i,k;
srand(time(NULL));
int matriz[6][6];
int vector[12];
for (a=1;a<=12;a+=1) {
    c = 0;
    d = (1+rand()%50);
    for (b=1;b<=12;b+=1) {
        if (d==vector[b-1]) {
            c = 1;
        }
    }
    if (c==1) {
        a = a-1;
    } else {
        vector[a-1] = d;
    }
}
for (a=1;a<=12;a+=1) {
    printf("%i\n",vector[a-1]);
}
printf("\n");
for (h=1;h<=6;h+=1) {
    for (i=1;i<=6;i+=1) {
        matriz[h-1][i-1] = vector[(1+rand()%12)-1];
    }
}
for (f=1;f<=6;f+=1) {
    for (k=1;k<=6;k+=1) {
        printf(" | %i",matriz[f-1][k-1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}
[image: Captura de la ejecución del programa]

Comment: Ideas sueltas: Tendrías que llevar una matriz de cada valor y el número de ocurrencias, validar si es 3 o más y volver a buscar otro valor aleatorio. Podrías ir modificando el vector de valores a usar, sacando los que ya no aplican y llevándolos a un vector de valores agotados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es nada práctico generar números aleatorios y comprobar que cumplen unas limitaciones; esto da lugar a un algoritmo potencialmente infinito en el peor de los casos y en el mejor de los casos lleva a generar y descartar varios números. Olvídalo: borra todo tu código e intenta algo diferente:

1. Genera 12 números aleatorios sin repeticiones entre 1 y 50.
2. Triplica los 12 números generados.
3. Guarda los números en una matriz.

Para cumplir con el primer punto, podemos partir de una lista de números de 1 a 50 y desordenarla:

```
int numeros[50] {};
std::generate(numeros, numeros + 50, [n = 0]() mutable { return ++n; });

std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generador(device());
std::shuffle(numeros, numeros + 50, generador);
```

Esto garantiza que no habrán repeticiones de números, así que si nos quedamos con los 12 primeros ya cumplimos con el primer punto, si los guardamos en un contenedor por triplicado cumplimos con el segundo:

```
std::vector<int> aleatorios;
for (int indice = 0; indice != 12; ++indice)
{
    aleatorios.push_back(numeros[indice]);
    aleatorios.push_back(numeros[indice]);
    aleatorios.push_back(numeros[indice]);
}
// Desordenamos los tripletes
std::shuffle(aleatorios.begin(), aleatorios.end(), generador);
```

Finalmente sólo queda guardarlos en la matriz:

```
int matriz[6][6];
auto numero = aleatorios.begin();
for (auto &fila : matriz)
{
    for (auto &valor : fila)
    {
        valor = *numero;
        ++numero;
        std::cout << valor << '\t';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVJhT4MwEP1Mf8UZEwE3F6aZZsD2RxgxHRTWWNqllH1w4bdjS0GGxm8mJPTu3t2999rsfH7KGOZl191TnrEmJxBTUStJcLVHUw6zUkiqTrOkxDwXs8yFZErIPUKUK6gw5Z6PrsgxEW8qIkWdbIIUrm2EnFrlYVgSTiRWxBvKyxEHC9gES0g47CBIPR@qRuEjI3AFSVQjOSwWPILWj9AwyrJ5z8mFZgTsb1xTqfV2@/IGdl0upGfrnu@PkPrUFAX7k8h357TQio21uD1gRrAOtHV6XiEkeEYz5bnhohVE4/luB@vnSJO3sY8c7Y8zta/OTX16P@LsY2SSWGRqmP4/sP0h/6bvSEpzgcsbcSvCc5OZu2EvW0n6mbym@tNjcaPE4KCW/3vo6FKPeygowxAOMwZLbsoXzHQQgoHpal92bHIHj3aL0ezoJzEFvaxMNAriGCxaH9yDck1Z654j3AN3ez@QMzywIEJt130B)</kbd>.